# MySql Smaller than Quantity with Group By Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

In report table, there are multiple date_time and quantity records for each day. I want to select sum of quantity smaller than 3 for each day's record separately.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT
  DATE(date_time) AS date_time,
  SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM report
WHERE date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND quantity < 3
GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
```

Table Example:

```
| date_time           | quantity
-------------------------
| 2017-08-12 09:11:51 | 1
| 2017-08-12 10:12:51 | 1
| 2017-08-12 12:45:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 11:12:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 11:12:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 12:45:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 13:57:51 | 1
| 2017-08-14 14:23:51 | 1
| 2017-08-14 16:34:51 | 1
| 2017-08-15 16:21:51 | 1
| 2017-08-16 14:31:51 | 1
```

After selection:

```
| date_time  | quantity
 -------------
| 2017-08-14 | 2
| 2017-08-15 | 1
| 2017-08-16 | 1
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Have a look at [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause

Comment: Add `HAVING sum(quantity) < 3` at the end of your query

Comment: Be wary of using `between` with datetime. See [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: `date_time >= '2017-08-01' AND date_time < '2018-09-01'`, for example *(as per @HoneyBadger)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** You need to use `HAVING` to filter the group whereas `WHERE` filters rows

```
SELECT DATE(date_time) as date_time
    ,SUM(quantity) as quantity
FROM report
WHERE date_time BETWEEN '' AND  ''
GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
HAVING SUM(quantity) < 3  --Before it was data specific COUNT(quantity)
```

Comment: How can I sum up quantity after selection? As I demonstrate above, can I get result as 4 after selection without date_time?

Comment: If you still want to sum it and return single row as desired output then you have to use sub query. Try yourself first if won't get any idea please reply.